# BigQuery stored procedure access through simba jdbc driver

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, google-bigquery, simba

All,
I am trying to execute a stored procedure in google bigquery using a jdbc connection but having no luck with it.

I followed the example here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures.

I am able to create and call the stored procedure from bigquery web ui but when i set up a data source in intellij using the simba driver as explained here https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/07/10/using-bigquery-from-intellij-based-ide/

Then when i run the call to execute the stored procedure

```
DECLARE target_employee_id INT64 DEFAULT 9;
DECLARE employee_hierarchy ARRAY<INT64>;
dataset.GetEmployeeHierarchy(target_employee_id, employee_hierarchy);
SELECT target_employee_id, employee_hierarchy;
```

i get an error

```
[HY000][100032] [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Unrecognized name: target_employee_id at [1:8] com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Unrecognized name: target_employee_id at [1:8]
```

As the stored procedure support is in pre-release beta, I am wondering if the Simba driver supports it as of now?
If not are there any other jdbc drivers that do currently?

Comment: I'm guessing it simply doesn't support it yet. The release notes show the last release being in March 2019: https://cdn.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/Simba_BigQuery_JDBC_ReleaseNotes.txt

Comment: Cool, seems like it. Ended up reporting an issue in Google issues tracker

Comment: Hi, if this is your [google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/150516302) please can you update this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out all the 4 statements need to be executed as a single Bloc not as individual statements. 
In intellij you can highlight all those statements and hit run to execute it and return the results.
In Java just pass them as a single string in statement.execute.